# Como converter CamelCase para snake_case em PHP (de maneira mais simples)?

Tags: php, camel-case, snake-case

Como faço para converter uma `string` com *CamelCase* para *snake_case* em PHP de maneira mais simples possível?

Exemplo:

```
CamelCase => camel_case
AjaxInfo  => ajax_info
```

Comment: `$saida = ltrim(strtolower(preg_replace('/[A-Z]/', '_$0', $entrada )), '_');`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pronta com uma linha tem [essa do SOzão](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19533226/916193)

```
$saida = ltrim(strtolower(preg_replace('/[A-Z]/', '_$0', $entrada )), '_');
```

A pergunta é: e o que acontece se tiver `___` no começo?

Só que pode ser interessante mudar a lógica se sempre for começar por uma letra:

```
$saida = substr(strtolower(preg_replace('/[A-Z]/', '_$0', $entrada )), 1);
```

Essa aqui já garante o primeiro caractere não ter `_` usando `lcfirst`:

```
$saida = strtolower( preg_replace(
    ["/([A-Z]+)/", "/_([A-Z]+)([A-Z][a-z])/"], ["_$1", "_$1_$2"], lcfirst($entrada) ) );
```

**Observações:**

- Veja estas situações:

  ```
  LetraEMaiuscula 
  CodeIsHTML
  ```

  No primeiro caso, usar `[a-z][A-Z]` dá problema. No segundo caso, `[a-z][A-Z]` é melhor que só `[A-Z]`. Se precisar do segundo caso tem que usar uma troca no formato `([A-Z])([A-Z][a-z])` por `$1_$2`
- E se tiver espaços? Acredito que se já é CamelCase bem formado, não faz sentido ter espaços na string, mas se precisar trocar por `_`, é o caso de acrescentar um `str_replace(' ', '_', $valor )` como já se precaveu o Miguel na [resposta dada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/138692/70).

Comment: O problema é se tiver espaço. Não devia substituir também por '_'?

Comment: @Miguel boa pergunta. Depende de como a pessoa vai usar. Adicionei uma observação.

Comment: Percebi claro que se é CamelCase parte-se do pincípio que não há espaços

Comment: @Miguel de qq forma acho válida sua observação, afina, nunca sabemos como a pessoa vai usar o código.